# How to setup/install vstest.console.exe in github actions?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, code-coverage, .net-4.8

I am trying to run test cases for .Net Framework v4.6 project and want to add vstest into github actions, Can anyone suggests how to setup vstest in Github runner?

I have tried vstest-action of microsoft but facing issue as No matched tests file found.

Answer (score 0):

try https://github.com/darenm/Setup-VSTest

```
- name: Setup VSTest Path
  uses: darenm/Setup-VSTest@v1.2
  
- name: VSTest
  run: vstest.console.exe /Platform:x64 .\test\sample.app.dll
```